# java - use Object as parameter in method signature versus method overloading

Tags: java

I have a method in which I need to pass to it either a single domain object or a collection of them. Processing of the parameter passed differs slightly depending on whether it's a single instance or a collection.
May I ask for advice on the best approach ? Should I make the method signature accept an Object type and then process with `instanceof` and downcasting as below ?

```
private static synchronized void mymethod(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof List ) {
  ...
  }
  else if (obj instanceof MyObjectClass) {
  ... 
  }
}
```

Or should I use overloading ? Any pitfalls in each case ?
I understand the first case is a bit dangerous as it could accept anything passed to it, however my code is not meant to be used as an API or extended etc.

Comment: keep your code readable, go for overloaded

Comment: Overloading gives you compile-time assurance that someone isn't calling your method with any old junk `mymethod("foo")`. Your version does not.

Comment: Is the logic when handling the list different than a single object? or is it the same, just repeated for all objects in the list?

Comment: @jbx the logic is slightly different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different approaches to this kind of design "problem".

Using method overloads:

```
void myMethod(final MyObject myObject);
void myMethod(final List<? extends MyObject> myObjects);
```

Using a var-args input parameter:

```
void myMethod(final MyObject... myObject);

   -> myMethod(myObject);
   -> myMethod(myObject, myOtherObject);
   -> myMethod(myObjectsArray);     // myObjectsArray = new MyObject[]
```

Using a `Collection`/`List` as input parameter:

```
void myMethod(final Collection<? extends MyObject> myObjects);

   -> myMethod(Collections.singletonList(myObject));
   -> myMethod(myObjectCollection); // List<MyObject>, Set<MyObject>, Collection<MyObject>
```

Personally I'd go with method overloads, as the internal logic usually changes, slightly maybe, but it changes. The intent is more clear, and JavaDoc can be customized for the single method.

I'm a "picky" developer, and I prefer explicitly stating that there can be two forms of input. I prefer overloads even when it might be not necessary **(at the moment)**. In that case I just delegate to the `Collection<?>` method, or the opposite.

```
void myMethod(final MyObject object) {
   myObject(Collections.singletonSet(object));
}
```

But that is based on opinions.

I'd say the most important aspect is, **don't duplicate code!**

Answer (score 2):

Overloading is usually the way to go in such situations. Remember that the generic type of the list is actually 'type erased' at runtime, so you won't really know that your `List` is actually a `List<MyObjectClass>`. Overloading will give you compile time checks, so it's safer.

When using generics also think if your `MyObjectClass` is going to be extended in some way. And you might get a collection of those objects instead.

Also, as a general pattern, try to avoid repeating code in both overloaded methods. So if you are doing the same thing on all objects when you pass a `List` you can call one method from the other as follows:

```
private static synchronized void mymethod(MyObjectClass obj) {
  //todo: do the logic on the object
}

private static synchronized void mymethod(Collection<? extends MyObjectClass> collection) {
  //assuming the logic is the same, otherwise do whatever you need to do here
  collection.forEach(obj -> mymethod(obj));
}
```

Downcasting and `instanceof` are usually symptoms of design decisions that do not quite fit what you need. Sometimes it is difficult to get out of them, and you have to resort to them, but in general it is ideal to let the compiler verify your types and do the right method resolution for the behaviour you want.

Comment: In many years I've had to resort to instanceof or .class comparison only in "core" classes. I think the important thing when dealing with them is focusing everything in a small portion of code, so to keep the maintainability costs as little as possible. But they shouldn't escape from that layer. Generics can do everything.

Comment: @LppEdd Yep agreed. Sometimes you end up in a corner and you have to use them surgically to avoid having to refactor everything. But in general best try to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading suffice your need. I can think of following ways

`private static synchronized void mymethod(MyObjectClass myObj){
...
}
private static synchronized void mymethod(Collection<MyObjectClass> myObj){
...
}`

TreffnonX has already given more detailed and generic-based correct approach while i was editing my answer. Refer to it :)

Answer (score -1):

Overloading the method seems more correct here, though both versions would work. That way, the compiler can evaluate the code as far as possible. However your code seems a bit incomplete, to be honest. My personal approach would be to go even further and generalize the method with a generic Type:

```
private static synchronized <T extends MyObjectClass> void mymethod(T obj) {
    ...
}
private static synchronized <T extends MyObjectClass> void mymethod(Collection<T> obj) {
    ...
}
```

The advantage of this version is, that whatever you do inside your `mymethod`, you can return stuff related to the type, and modern IDEs can greatly help your evaluation and resolve Lambdas better.

Also, why specifically a `List`? Does a `Collection` do? Usually when you limit yourself to lists, you miss out on `Sets` and other important collections.

Comment: You don't need the generics. He wants to operate on one or more `MyObjectClass`s, not any old objects. It should just be `MyObjectClass` and `Collection<MyObjectClass>`. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: With this solution you cannot call the methods of `MyObjectClass` because you are losing its type.

Comment: @jbx Correct. I overlooked that, since OP initially only went for Object-parameter only, but you are right. Fixed the answer.

Comment: OK, but the argument of the first `mymethod` does not need to be a generic parameter. It just needs to be `MyObjectClass`. Revise a bit basic OOP before posting answers.